# How to count white pixel in each contour

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour

I have an algorithm to count the number of people in video. Here is the concept:

background subtraction > Thresholding > canny > findcontour > sum the white pixel in each contour and make them to array list.

[image]

So, I want the output becomes examplearray = [sum the number of pixel in right box, sum the number of pixel in left box]

I think I can do it with this code

```
line=[]

for area in cv2.contourArea(cnt):

    count=np.sum(box == 255)
    line.append(count)
```

but I'am not sure, the code is error saying can only iterate in interger not float. Other than that, I'am not sure about my code yet.

Comment: what is `box` in the code?

Comment: it's a mask containing the white pixel only in video after through the process of background subtraction

Comment: `count=np.sum(box == 255)` is the correct thing to do. Please elaborate your error/problem.

Comment: for i in cv2.contourArea(cnt):
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: `cv.connectedComponentsWithStats`. `contourArea` is not iterable, it returns a number. why do you think your code should work?

Comment: If you need more help than the hints in the comments please share a reproducible minimal code example.

Comment: @Alfarezamahendra draw each individual contour on an empty image of same shape and count the white pixels